# How do I constrain an SKShapeNode to the device edges in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, constraints, skshapenode

Just to test things out I have created a blue square and placed it at the center of the screen like this:

```
let mySquare = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

mySquare.fillColor = SKColor.blue
mySquare.lineWidth = 1
let myPoint = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.midX, y: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.midY)

mySquare.position.x = 0
mySquare.position.y = 0

self.addChild(mySquare)
```

Works great. Now, I would like to use `constraints` and set up the square `constraints` to the edges of the device screen. I have tried this, but the blue square doesn't appear, so I think I have the wrong idea on how to capture the `CGPoint` of the screen edges.

```
let mySquare = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

        mySquare.fillColor = SKColor.blue
        mySquare.lineWidth = 1
        let myPoint = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.maxX, y: UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.maxY)

        let range = SKRange(lowerLimit: 10.0, upperLimit: 10.0)
        let myConstraints = SKConstraint.distance(range, to: myPoint)

        mySquare.constraints = [myConstraints]
        self.addChild(mySquare)
```

How do I capture the screen edges and constrain the square to those?

Answer (score 0):

SKConstraint doesn't work equally as UIKit Constraints.

SKConstraint functionality is really specific:

Please take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skconstraint

Anyway, can give you some recommendations:

1. Transform screen position to scene position:

```swift
self.view?.convert(myPoint, to: self)
```

2. You can start with this example and get node on a corner

```swift
let mySquare = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
mySquare.fillColor = SKColor.blue
mySquare.lineWidth = 1
let myScreenPoint = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY)
if let myScenePoint = self.view?.convert(myScreenPoint, to: self) {
    mySquare.position = myScenePoint
}
self.addChild(mySquare)
```

3. With this logic, you can get each side of the screen and decrease or increase margin and make each 4 sides; or 1 constraint for the center.

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite think I grasp the need to convert though. Are you saying that there are two sets of coordinate systems? If that's the case, that would explain why I can't use UIScreen.main.bounds when calculating where to position a node. Anyway, tried your code, but it didn't even go into the if let to set the position. Tried without if let, and if just returned nil. Really appreciate you trying to help me out. by the way!